# Android. sent multiply-attachement email

Tags: android, email, attachment

I would like to send email via

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)))
```

I know that to attach file to email I need

```
intentEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, <Uri of file>)
```

but I need to attach several files. How can I do this?

Comment: I will marrk this question opened but I found a workaround:
use ZipOutputStream to make compressed zip file of files I would like to attach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to send multiple attachments

```
public static void sendEmail(Context context, String emailTo, String emailCC,
            String subject, String message, List<String> filePaths)
        {
            //send email with multiple attachments
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
                new String[]{emailTo});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, 
                new String[]{emailCC});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
                    subject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                    message);
            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            //convert from paths to Uri's
            for (String file : filePaths)
            {
                File fileIn = new File(file);
                Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                uris.add(u);
         }

            emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            context.startActivity(emailIntent);
        }
```